# select minimum date and other column value for maximum date

Tags: mysql, maxdate, mindate

need to return minimum date and other column value for maximum date like below

```
id  name    date        item
1   First1  24/03/2001  abc
2   First1  20/12/2002  bcd
3   First1  13/02/2003  xyz
4   first2  24/03/2004  nhe
5   first2  20/12/2005  djp
6   first2  13/02/2006  pqr
```

Required output:

```
name    min_date    max_item
First1  24/03/2001  xyz
first2  24/03/2004  pqr
```

for each contact need to dispaly the min date and item value for max date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to get the overall minimum and maximum for the table.

```
(select t.*
 from table t
 order by date asc
 limit 1
)
union all
(select t.*
 from table t
 order by date desc
 limit 1
)
```